# iOS xamarin - Crash on first launch while In app purchase

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

We have used Azure SDK in our xamarin app. 
When we are login using google or Facebook using Azure in our app and then go for the subscription using In app purchase, app is crashing in iOS.

As soon as the In app purchase dialog is open, app is getting crashed.

Also, it is crashing while making subscription for the first time after app install. Then everything is working fine.

Please have a look below detailed error log.

```
2019-02-08 17:19:59.065 EarnieJr.iOS[4133:1596190] [AppCenterCrashes] ERROR: +[MSWrapperLogger MSWrapperLog:tag:level:]/7 Unhandled Exception:
UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00020] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:89 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr sel, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.g.cs:235 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (System.EventHandler notification, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00048] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:116 
  at UIKit.UIControl.remove_TouchUpInside (System.EventHandler value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:182 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00017] in <55e20ffeeae44e4d8fcf262393127192>:0 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:143 
2019-02-08 17:19:59.072 EarnieJr.iOS[4133:1596190] [AppCenterCrashes] WARNING: +[MSWrapperLogger MSWrapperLog:tag:level:]/7 Cannot serialize UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException exception for client side inspection. If you want to have access to the exception in the callbacks, please add a Serializable attribute and a deserialization constructor to the exception class.
2019-02-08 17:19:59.082 EarnieJr.iOS[4133:1596190] Unhandled managed exception:
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread. (UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00020] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:89 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (Foundation.NSObject target, System.IntPtr sel, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.g.cs:235 
  at UIKit.UIControl.RemoveTarget (System.EventHandler notification, UIKit.UIControlEvent events) [0x00048] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:116 
  at UIKit.UIControl.remove_TouchUpInside (System.EventHandler value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIControl.cs:182 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00017] in <55e20ffeeae44e4d8fcf262393127192>:0 
  at Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:143
```

Version details are as below for used packages,

"Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" Version="4.1.1"

"Plugin.InAppBilling" Version="2.0.0"

"Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.5.0.129452"

var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
var purchase = await billing.PurchaseAsync("ProductId here", ItemType.Subscription, "devId");

Comment: `UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread. `

Comment: Check the code in the `MSWrapperLogger MSWrapperLog:tag:level:`.